# Slant asymptote for unusual function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose $f(\lambda) = \det (A + \lambda B)$

Do you know any square matrices A and B over R such that $f(\lambda)$ has slant (horizontal is not allowed) asymptote?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the function $f$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$. Can you make it to have degree $1$?