# Properties of $f(x) = \det (A+xB)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> Let $A_{n \times n},B_{n \times n}$ be real square matrices. Let $f(x) = \det (A+xB)$. Then
>
> 1. if n is odd, then $f(x)$ has inflection point
> 2. $f(x)$ doesn't have a horizontal asymptote
> 3. there exists matrices A,B such that $f(x)$ has slant (which is neither vertical, nor horizontal) asymptote
> 4. if n is even, then $f(x)$ has point of local minimum

It's easy to refute (1): $A = B = 0 \Rightarrow f(x) = 0$ has no inflection point.

How to disprove (2) and (4) and prove (3)?

Note: I've found that someone asked about (3) here: [Slant asymptote for unusual function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434269/slant-asymptote-for-unusual-function) but I don't get the hint, well, I understand that having polynomial of degree one would imply the existence of $\lim f(x) / x$, which is necessary condition for slant asymptote. But I failed to come up with A,B that give such polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) Pick $A = [0]$ and $B = [0]$. Then $f(x) = 0$, which has a horizontal asymptote of $y = 0$.

3) Pick $A = [0]$ and $B = [1]$. Then $f(x) = x$, which has a slant asymptote of $y = x$.

4) Pick $A = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $f(x) = -x^2$ which does not have a local minimum.